# Not able to use MockK library in KMM project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, mockk

`Could not resolve io.mockk:mockk:1.13.2 for :shared:iosArm64Test Could not resolve io.mockk:mockk:1.13.2 for :shared:iosSimulatorArm64Test Could not resolve io.mockk:mockk:1.13.2 for :shared:iosX64Test`

Found that MockK is only supported for jvm target - https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/950

But what i know is the unit tests we write on common shared module are meant to be run on local machine (mac/ windows) which do have have JVM installed.

Please can anyone add some light over here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use mockk only in jvm test sources. If you write common code, and you have native targets, it won't work.

So, you can add `jvmTest` instead of `commonTest` and write tests in `jvmTest` that use mockk. However, that won't test your native code directly.